# JTable onchange event

Tags: java, events, jtable

Is there any way to detect a cell **selection** change in a JTable? I've found documentation for detecting a  row change using ListSelectionListener but it doesn't seam to work when changing selection on the same row. I'm using JTable to render a simple schedule.

Maybe I should use a different component?

Comment: Your wording is a bit ambiguous. I suggest you clarify whether you're looking for data or selection changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the right component for showing tabular data is JTable.

You want to add a listener to the TableModel that's underneath the table. That will fire off events whenever data changes. You get it out of JTable, unsurprisingly enough, by calling `getTableModel()`.

---

**Update**

Oh wait, I think I misunderstood you. You're not interested in data changes but column selection changes.

JTable has a method called `columnSelectionChanged`; its documentation says it's called by `TableColumnModelListener`, which leads me to believe that what you want to do is `getColumnModel()` and use the `addColumnModelListener()` method of that to listen for column selection changes.